# cURL timezone in response body

Tags: http, curl, timezone

There's a way to change timezone in response body using curl (CEST instead of GMT)?

E.G.

```
 curl -v http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone
    Trying 10.247.129.103... connected
    
    * HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
    < HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    **< Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2020 10:38:06 GMT**

Europe/Rome
```

Server TZ is :

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
# The time zone of the system is defined by the contents of /etc/localtime.
# This file is only for evaluation by system-config-date, do not rely on its
# contents elsewhere.
ZONE="Europe/Rome"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking about the `Date` in the HTTP response.  It's a *header* - not in the response body.

This header has nothing to do with cURL.  It's the standard HTTP `Date` header, that every HTTP server must include in its response.  It's defined in [RFC 7231 Section 7.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1), and it *must* always be in terms of GMT.

This particular website you are calling is using a geolocation technique to resolve an approximate [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (`Europe/Rome` in your example) from the caller's IP address.  You can take this identifier and use it in your own logic to resolve the current time in that time zone.  For example, after your cURL call, assuming you are using a Linux distribution that has a `tzdata` package installed (which most do), you can set the [`TZ`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) environment variable and use the [`date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command like this:

```sh
TZ=Europe/Rome date
```

Example output:

```
Mon Oct 12 18:50:04 CEST 2020
```

There are plenty of other ways you can use the time zone in different programming languages and environments, so choose an approach that works for your use case.